# How Can I Use expose-loader with .jsx Files to Enable User Scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I would like to expose the codebase of project written mostly in react in webpack so that users can inject and modify UI code on the fly. This is simple for the .js files and libraries:

```
//webpack.config.js,
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: require.resolve("Library"),
            loader: "expose-loader?Library"
        },
```

Now I have, as you would expect a variable *Library* with everything that should be there. However, when I try to expose a react component (.jsx) with:

```
   test: require.resolve("./src/AwesomeComponent.jsx"),
   loaders: ["expose-loader?AwesomeComponent", "babel-loader"]
```

I just get an empty variable *AwesomeComponent*. What am I missing here?

Comment: Related https://github.com/handsontable/react-handsontable/issues/11?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps. But I am looking to expose react components to other libraries, as opposed to the other way around. Also, may be relevant, I am using webpack 3.5.4.